# PHP foreach all characters

Tags: php, loops, utf-8, foreach, character

So far I have this:

```
foreach (range('A', 'Z') as $char) {
    echo $char . "\n";
}
```

And it prints out the alphabet.

But I need something that will have the full aplhabet, numbers, symbols and foreign characters.

Let's say that I am trying to get every single human readable UTF-8 Character in the Basic Latin part.

Is this possible and if so what would I need to do?

Comment: "And foreign characters"? Like, *all ~120,000+* of them?

Comment: It's possible, but you'd need to write some code to do it.... I'd recommend a Generator

Comment: Which character set?

Comment: @Federico UTF-8? Or would that be too intense? Or maybe just some of the ascii characters and symbols?

Comment: Here's the utf-8 table: http://www.utf8-chartable.de/ You want all of them?

Comment: @Federico pretty much to be honest.. I need to loop through as many characters as I can which is reasonable considering a lot will have foreign characters

Comment: Why the downvotes? I didn't commit a sin by asking a question which might not be logically possible :/

Comment: It's a badly defined question and as such less useful to others. Tell us exactly what you want and we can tell you how to do it, or that it's not possible and why it's not possible. At the moment it's neither here nor there.

Comment: "Let's say that I am trying to get every single human readable UTF-8 Character in the Basic Latin part." updated my qestion @deceze

Comment: The best idea is to get a copy of the Unicode database and filter the characters based on your criteria. unicode.org is the source, but you can probably find alternative sources for already pre-processed data somewhere.

Comment: Would you consider a, ä, ă, à, å and á to be Latin characters? How about ǻ, ầ, ậ, ẳ and ẫ ?

Comment: @RocketNuts yes i would

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2<sup>32</sup> > 4 billion unicode characters. Most of them are not used or allocated yet, but even the first 2<sup>16</sup> is probably way more than you want.

Here's an example that will output characters 32-2047, but of course there are many textual characters beyond 2047 as well (mostly non-Latin though).

```php
$s = "All characters: ";

for ($c=32; $c<2047; $c++)
{
    $s .= json_decode('"\u'.bin2hex(pack('n', $c)).'"');
}

print($s);
```

Answer (score 2):

`range` function go through the `ASCII` characters. Use the first one and last one you want. Here I'm using `!` and `~`.

```
foreach (range('!', '~') as $char) {
    echo $char . "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
! " # $ % & ' ( ) * + , - . / 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 : ; < = > ? @ A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z [ \ ] ^ _ ` a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z { | } ~
```

---

Alternatively, you can also use `for` and `chr` like below.

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 255; $i++) {
    echo chr($i);
}
```